# Ruby-on-Rails how to store ip address of visitors in database when submitting new registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, devise, ip, store

I'm currently able to display visitors IP in a stored variable using this :

```
    <% @ip_address = request.remote_ip %>
    <%= @ip_address %>
```

Now that's done, I would like to include this value in the new_registration_form in order to store visitor IP in my Postresql database.

After many searches on the web and unsuccessful attempts, I'm here to ask for help to explain me how to include this variable as hidden field in the registration_form, and store the value in de database as `user.ip_address`

please find below my files :

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), data: {turbo: false}) do |form| %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <% @ip_address = request.remote_ip %>
    <% form.label :ip_address %>
    <% form.text_field :ip_address, class: 'form-control', value: @ip_address  %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @ip_address = request.remote_ip
    @user.ip_address = @ip_address

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "Account created successfully." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "Account updated successfully." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: "Account deleted successfully." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name)
    end
end
```

console output

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2022-10-24 15:25:28 +0200
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Nicolas", "last_name"=>"Donald", "email"=>"nicodonald@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"submit"}
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "nicodonald@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Exists? (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "nicodonald@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."phone_number" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["phone_number", "0607080919"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "first_name", "last_name", "ip_address", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "nicodonald@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "[FILTERED]"], ["reset_password_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["reset_password_sent_at", "[FILTERED]"], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["first_name", "Nicolas"], ["last_name", "Donald"], ["ip_address", nil], ["created_at", "2022-10-24 13:25:28.622646"], ["updated_at", "2022-10-24 13:25:28.622646"]]
  TRANSACTION (1.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/home
Completed 302 Found in 173ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Allocations: 13474)
```

Whatever I try, I can't add any value for ip_address in the database when form submiting (ip_address remains : nil)

If you have any idea ... help would be appreciated ;)

TY in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but `ip_address` isn't really a param. I would try removing it from the `user_params` and `configure_permitted_parameters` methods (and remove the form field for it)

Comment: Is it important for you to have the user IP address in your form ? If not I think it would be better to avoid showing the user IP in the DOM and just setup the ip_address in your `create` method as you already do. And like @Hula_Zell answered you can remove it from your `configure_permitted_parameters`. You don't have any callback in your User model that could affect your ip_address column ? Also note that if you check the validity of an IP address and you test it in local your IP is `::1`

Comment: No, it's not important to show the IP in the form, it's just for testing that IP value is correct, I've edited my code in accordance with your comments. I haven't any callback in my user model that could affect the ip_address. I also know for local IP returning ::1, I'm testing this feature in production only